# showmount do not shows all the mount configuration

Tags: mount, nfs

I have a VM(nfs-node), it has NFS system.

In my nfs-node, I configured the `/etc/exports`:

```
/mnt/sdb/var/lib/glance *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
/mnt/sdb/var/lib/nova/instances *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

You see, I give two directory to share mount.

But I show mount in it :

```
[root@nfs-node instances]# showmount -e
Export list for nfs-node:
/mnt/sdb/var/lib/glance *
```

I get only the `/mnt/sdb/var/lib/glance`, the `/mnt/sdb/var/lib/nova/instances` do not shows up, why?

Answer (score 0):

You configured the `exports` file, you should restart the nfs server.
use the below command:

```
systemctl restart nfs-server
```